# Azure Python SDK Filter issue (Logic App Service)

Tags: python, azure-sdk, azure-sdk-python

I'm having issues using filters while retrieving data from azure (Logic apps). When using a filter to retrieve data from Azure I get an error while iterating over the iterator object returned. If re-running the code the error happens at different stages of the iteration process (e.g. sometimes it fails at the 3rd iteration sometimes at the 29th). Everything works well if no filter is used.

**Example 1 (workflow_runs)**:

```
response_runs = logic_app_client.workflow_runs.list(workflow_name=workflow, resource_group_name=resource_group, filter = "StartTime Gt 2022-09-23T15:02:16.078315Z")
for i, run in enumerate(response_runs):
   print(i)
```

Error:

```
HttpResponseError: (InvalidQueryFilter) The provided query filter 'StartTime Gt 2022-09-23T15:02:16.078315Z,StartTime Gt 2022-09-23T15:02:16.078315Z' is not valid or not supported.
Code: InvalidQueryFilter
Message: The provided query filter 'StartTime Gt 2022-09-23T15:02:16.078315Z,StartTime Gt 2022-09-23T15:02:16.078315Z' is not valid or not supported.
```

**Example 2 (workflow_trigger_histories)**:

```
trigger_histories =  logic_app_client.workflow_trigger_histories.list(resource_group_name=resource_group, trigger_name= trigger, workflow_name=workflow, filter="Status eq 'Succeeded'") 

for i, trigger_histroy in enumerate(trigger_histories):
    print(i)
```

Error:

```
HttpResponseError: (InvalidQueryFilter) The provided query filter 'Status eq 'Succeeded',Status eq 'Succeeded'' is not valid or not supported.
Code: InvalidQueryFilter
Message: The provided query filter 'Status eq 'Succeeded',Status eq 'Succeeded'' is not valid or not supported.
```

Any ideas about what is going wrong here?

Comment: try using "startTime" instead of "StartTime" in the filter

Comment: Same issue: 
`HttpResponseError: (InvalidQueryFilter) The provided query filter 'startTime Gt 2022-09-23T15:02:16.078315Z,startTime Gt 2022-09-23T15:02:16.078315Z' is not valid or not supported.
Code: InvalidQueryFilter
Message: The provided query filter 'startTime Gt 2022-09-23T15:02:16.078315Z,startTime Gt 2022-09-23T15:02:16.078315Z' is not valid or not supported.`


It looks a bit weird that the filter value that is returned in the error message is duplicated e.g.: `'startTime Gt 2022-09-23T15:02:16.078315Z,startTime Gt 2022-09-23T15:02:16.078315Z'`.

Comment: can you please rerun the code with "gt" instead of "Gt" the reason is that I think the components of query is case sensitive

Comment: `HttpResponseError: (InvalidQueryFilter) The provided query filter 'starTime gt 2022-09-23T15:02:16.078315Z' is not valid or not supported.
Code: InvalidQueryFilter
Message: The provided query filter 'starTime gt 2022-09-23T15:02:16.078315Z' is not valid or not supported.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The new library version of azure-mgmt-logic (v 10.1.0b1) solves the issue. Details:
[Github issue](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/issues/27228)